# Adding first minor version of component to a page

Tags: workflow, 2013-sp1

When a Component is created, it is configured to immediately enter Workflow and becomes version 0.1.

The editors would like to then add this version 0.1 to a Page, so it can be published to staging and approved in context.

However, when adding a Component Presentation only major versions are displayed. As there is no major version yet, the Component can not be added to the page.

What is the best option? I am thinking code to automatically accelerate from version 0.1 to version 1.1.

Update Following @Nuno's Answer

I like the idea of avoiding events system and keeping it contained as one workflow, however I receive the following error when using an Automatic Action (not automatic decision) step first. I will try automatic decision next.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many ways to skin this cat:

1. Upgrade to Web 8 :)
2. Use the API to add the component presentation to the page. The CM core won't stop you from doing this, it's only the UI logic that is stopping you. Do beware that if you do this you won't be able to cancel the workflow for the component (it's in use, so it can't be deleted).
3. As you state, write some event logic that turns 0.1 into 1.1 by finishing the workflow and then starting a new one.

For #3, which is rather common, you could build a "single step automatic approval" flow in your workflow, with a first automatic step that checks the item's version and routes it down that route (no need for event code).

Comment: I like the idea for first workflow activity, but in 2013SP1 I think the first activity has to be manual?

Comment: Nope. 2013 SP1 doesn't have this requirement

Comment: That is the error I get. I'll update the question

Comment: It is indeed a restriction for system-started worrkflow (means workflow which is tarted by applying of component process to a schema, page process to a structure group, etc.) However, it should be possible for manually started workflows like: process started on bundle or process created using API.